# How to split a delimited string to compose a dd command in bash?

Tags: string, bash, split, dd

I would like to read a config file that should look similar to what is shown below:

```
source/path:blocksize,offset,seek,count
source/path2:blocksize,offset,seek
source/path3:blocksize,offset
```

Where `source/path`,`source/path2` and `source/path3` are paths to some binary file and offset, seek, count and blocksize are respective values for `dd` command.
Note that the variables may vary, like some binary file may not have seek or both seek and count values for `dd` command.

How should I split the above lines to compose `dd` command like this
`dd if=${source/path} bs=${blocksize} seek=${seek} count=${count}`
`dd if=${source/path} bs=${blocksize} seek=${seek}`
`dd if=${source/path} bs=${blocksize}`?

It is ok if modification is required in the above format to make it easy for parsing cause I ran out of all possibilities that my naive mind can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Hope this helps:***

```
$ cat <<EOF | while read line; do arr=($(sed 's/[,:]/ /g' <<< $line)); echo "source:${arr[0]}  block:${arr[1]} offset:${arr[2]} seek:${arr[3]} count:${arr[4]}"; done
source/path:blocksize,offset,seek,count
source/path2:blocksize,offset,seek
source/path3:blocksize,offset
EOF
source:source/path  block:blocksize offset:offset seek:seek count:count
source:source/path2  block:blocksize offset:offset seek:seek count:
source:source/path3  block:blocksize offset:offset seek: count:
```

***General Idea:***

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

your_command | while read line; do 
        arr=($(sed 's/[,:]/ /g' <<< $line)); 
        echo "source:${arr[0]}  block:${arr[1]} offset:${arr[2]} seek:${arr[3]} count:${arr[4]}"
        
        # Do whatever processing & validation you want here
        # access from array : ${arr[0]}....${arr[n]}
        #

 done
```

***If you're having file then:***

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read line; do
       arr=($(sed 's/[,:]/ /g' <<< $line)); 
       echo "source:${arr[0]}  block:${arr[1]} offset:${arr[2]} seek:${arr[3]} count:${arr[4]}"
        
        # Do whatever processing & validation you want here
        # access from array : ${arr[0]}....${arr[n]}
        #

done < "path/to/your-file"
```